# only the first post is shown

Tags: theme-development

I want to show posts in index page but just the first one is shown!this is the code:

```
<div class="w3ls">
   <?php if(have_posts()):
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   ?>
   <div class="col-md-6 w3ls-right wow fadeInDown"  data-wow-duration=".8s" data-wow-delay=".2s">
       <div class="tc-ch">
          <div class="tch-img">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" style=" width: 400px !important; height: 300px !important;" alt=""/></a>
          </div>
            <h3><a href="singlepage.html">
                 <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h3>
                <h6>توسط <a href="singlepage.html">
                    <?php the_author() ?></a><?php the_date() ?></h6>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <div class="bht1">
                           <a href="singlepage.html">ادامه مطلب</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="soci">
                          <ul>
                            <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a class="twit" href="#"></a></li>
                            <li class="hvr-rectangle-out"><a class="drib" href="#"></a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

what is the problem?

Comment: It looks like a standard post loop, have you checking the reading settings that it isn't set to 1 post per page? Is there a `query_posts` call above  this code? I'm assuming this is `index.php` in your theme?

Comment: no I didn't set any number and there is no query_posts and yes It's index.php

Comment: There should always be a number there, if none is set, set one. Can you confirm that changing it to 10 shows 10 or does not show 10 posts?